# Grabbing text in a hidden window

Tags: delphi

I am using EmbeddedWB in Delphi to read information from an https web site. I am having trouble identifying a popup (tooltip) window during the navigation of the site. This is the only one of three popups which is giving me trouble. In the other two, I programmatically highlight text using the mouse and copy it to the clipboard to find out which window popped up, but in the third window this doesn't work. When I highlight and Ctrl-c manually it goes into the clipboard, but when I do it  programmatically the clipboard is always empty. I have tried sending a 'Ctrl-C' instead of Clipboard.AsText := WB1.GetSelectedText(False); but without success. 
Any ideas?

Comment: Maybe start by having a look at the source of the page to identify what creates the pop-up, then load the page into your EmbeddedWB and use the DOM to get at it?

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to do all of this without a browser?